# the breakpoints in slider splide js do not work

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, splidejs

I am working with the slider plugin Splide JS. And I pass the **options** like this (full render slider):

```
let custom_slider = new Splide(".custom_slider");

custom_slider.mount();

if (custom_slider.length === 2) {
    custom_slider.options = {
        perPage: 2,
        breakpoints: {
            550: {
                perPage: 1,
            },
        },
    };
}
```

All of the above **options work**, except for the **breakpoints**. And I really don't understand why this happens.

I'm trying to assign specific options depending on the installed slides count, getting it like this - `custom_slider.length`.

It's all good, it works, BUT NOT the **breakpoint** options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
let splide_length = document.querySelectorAll('.custom_slider .splide__slide').length;

if ( splide_length === 2 ) {

    let custom_slider = new Splide(".custom_slider", {
            perPage: 2,
            breakpoints: {
                550: {
                    perPage: 1,
                },
            },
        }).mount();

    } else {
    let custom_slider = new Splide(".custom_slider").mount();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried before to use the code inside event `mounted`. It doesn't work. And there are no errors in the console :(

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I updated my answer now. Let me know if it works